# What is the use of the email attribute in Stripe checkout form?

Tags: stripe-payments

In the Stripe checkout form, users are asked to enter the email when adding a card. The server can prepopulate it if it knows the email of the user.

```
<form action="your-server-side-code" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_JADHJSDHSJDHSJDHSDJDSHS"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="Widget"
    data-email="user@email.com"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

What is the use of this email  attribute? Even after submitting the Card to Stripe, the server has to still manually add the card to the user account after getting the token back from Stripe. If the email of the user is already known by the server what is the use of this attribute? Does Stripe use the value of email for something?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you specify email attribute , stripe will automatically populate email on that stripe payment pop-up , user will not an able to enter it manually.

Comment: Yeah. I know that. I was asking what does stripe do with the value of the email.

Comment: This will show in a merchant account as an identity with other information of card, transaction id etc.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe also uses email to send stripe payment receipt to the user. On every successful payment user will receive an email from the stripe. you can customize the email template sent by stripe to put your company logo in that.

Email is of more use in case of recurring payment. Stripe automatically sends a payment reminder to them if you configure for the due recurring payment.

Comment: payment receipt will only send to the customer if while charging customer if you pass email attribute there.

Comment: And as asked question email attribute is sign of something else not about  payment receipt.

Comment: hmm. I thought the recipient is send to the email of the Customer and not the email while adding the card?